# Validation Rule for Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, validation, validation-rule

I'm receiving an error for a validation rule. Any help would be great! Essentially I'm trying to create a validation on the opportunity record to say that If the stage= Closed Won or Sent Membership Agreement and the Profile = System Admin then we should require a Yes/No value for a field

1. Make three fields required if stage = Closed Won or Sent Membership Agreement
2. Only accept a Yes/No Value from one field
3. Only work for people with a System Admin profile

Formula

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL( StageName ,'Closed Won'),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Sent Membership Agreement"),
    ,ISBLANK(Existing_Aetna_Optum_Cigna_Clients__c),
    ISBLANK(Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c),
    ISBLANK(Looking_For_Practice_Growth__c), 
    AND(
        $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", 
        AND Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c <> Yes,No
    )
```

Comment: You have syntax errors - double commas, `<> Yes,No` is invalid, missing final paren for the initial AND, last AND is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting your validation rule as if it were code (i.e. splitting individual components onto separate lines, and using indentation) is a simple and helpful way to work out a wide range of syntax issues.

By applying that to your formula, I can see

- You have an extra comma between the second `ISPICKVAL()` and the first `ISBLANK()`
- You have an extra `AND` in your nested `AND()`
- You're trying to compare multiple values with a single operator (Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c <> Yes,No)
- Your outermost `AND()` is missing a closing parenthesis

There are also some semantic (logical) issues

- You're looking for Stagename = closed won *and* Stagename = Sent Membership Agreement (instead of if the Stagename is one *or* the other)
- You're excluding the system administrator profile instead of enforcing this rule for that profile

When writing validation rules, it helps to remember that they're actually *invalidation* rules. They tell you when data is invalid. With that in mind, you're looking for something closer to this:

```
AND(
    /* A single field can only take a single value, so you need OR */
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won'),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Sent Membership Agreement')
    ),
    /* Only enforce if the user is a sysadmin, need to use '=' here */
    $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator',
    /* We should complain if _either_ of the first two fields are blank,*/
    /*   if the final field is blank, or if it isn't blank but not yes/no */
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Existing_Aetna_Optum_Cigna_Clients__c),
        ISBLANK(Looking_For_Practice_Growth__c),
        ISBLANK(Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c),
        AND(
            Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c <> 'yes',
            Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c <> 'no'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Still running into some issues. Am I missing something?                              
  AND(OR(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won'),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Sent Membership Agreement'),
    $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator',
       OR(
        ISBLANK(Existing_Aetna_Optum_Cigna_Clients__c),
        ISBLANK(Looking_For_Practice_Growth__c),
        ISBLANK(Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c),
        AND(
            Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c <> 'yes',
            Accepts_Insurance_before_ABC__c <> 'no'
        )
    )
)

Comment: @MonicaMickel You should copy/paste that formula into a text editor and break things onto individual lines (and indent) similar to what I have done. Then compare that to the example I've provided to see if there are any differences (and where they are). I can tell you right now that you're missing a close paren somewhere.